# Why was this answer marked as disputed then closed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

This answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/634310/17178 does not seem to warrant a content dispute warning or forced hidden and deletion.

Why did it receive that.

Comment: Good question, have to wait for Sam to come back online to answer this one

Comment: @VoltageSpike - Hi, I'll link you to the note.

Comment: @VoltageSpike - Link sent.

Comment: The more important question is why it was not immediately closed as a consumer repair question.

Comment: @pipe because it has an understanding of the underlying issues. Repair questions are allowed. Read the close reason text and the faqs.

Comment: Looks to me like encouraging the guy raising the question to bodge-fix the problem is dangerous advice. Get a new one in other words.

Comment: @Andyaka so then shouldn't the accepted 6 upvote answer by a mod saying the same thing also be deleted and content warning?

Comment: @Passerby there were clear indications in the accepted answer to get a new switch as I read it.

Answer (score 3):

There are genuine moderation reasons for that deletion (same has been done on a few others too) and it's not actually due to the content. However there are limited options in the list of reasons and "content dispute" is the closest "label" that we can choose from. We are unable to explain more due to privacy reasons of the account(s) involved. The reason has been explained to other mods in private communication.

Comment: This answer has 2 downvotes and 2 upvotes. On meta a downvote is an entirely valid way of showing disagreement with the general gist of an answer.In this case, how would downvoters suggest things be done in such a manner that a downvote was not in order? "Privacy reasons" are often annoying, but we are hoist with them as part of modern life. Moderators are limited in what they can say both by site CofC and general legal reasons. How would the downvoters suggest that moderators deal with this?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -- a thankless job.